# why wont the execute-mysqlcommand connect to the server and run the strings

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am trying to log onto the server and the database and have the command run the connection strings. all that happens is when i run the command posted below.

```
function Execute-MySqlcommand {param( [string]$Server,    #the host of the SQL server
                                    [string]$Database1,   #the name of the database
                                    [System.Data.MySqlclient.MySqlcommand]$Command)  #the command to execute (name of stored command)

 $mysqlConnection = new-object System.Data.MySqlclient.MySqlConnection
 $MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "DROP_VIEW DATABASE.BTXADDR;DROP_VIEW DATABASE.BTXSUPB;CREATE_VIEW DATABASE.BTXADDR FOR DATABASE1.DATABASE1S2.BTXADDR;CREATE_VIEW DATABASE.BTXSUPB FOR DATABASE1.DATABASE1S3.BTXSUPB"
 $MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE1.DATABASE1S2.BTXADDR;TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE1.DATABASE1S3.BTXSUPB; INSERT INTO DATABASE1.DATABASE1S3.BTXSUPB SELECT * FROM DATABASE1.DATABASE1S2.BTXSUPB; select count(*) from DATABASE1.DATABASE.BTXADDR; select count(*) from DATABASE1S.DATABASE.BTXADDR; select count(*) from DATABASE1.DATABASE.BTXSURB; select count(*) from DATABASE1S.DATABASE.BTXSUPB;"

 $Command.CommandType = 1 # 1 is the 'Text' command type
 $Command.Connection = $mysqlConnection

 $mysqlConnection.Open()
 $Result = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
 $mysqlConnection.Close()

 if ($Result -gt 0) {return $True} else {return $False}

}
```

all that happens when the command is run is shows that nothing I wrote in the script is wrong and then exits the script. But I am trying to Logon to the server and run script commands.

I have logged onto the server by myself to check to see if the command was actually ran and it shows the original views that were inplace before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string shouldn't contain the SQL you want to run.  If you're connecting with a Windows domain account it would be

```
$mysqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$Server;Database=$Database1;Integrated Security=True"
```

For the commands

```
$command.CommandText = 'Drop View or whatever SQL you want to run'
$returnVal = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: I changed the script to do that and it still didn't connect to the server.

Comment: I feel stupid I foregot to change permissions in powershell to enable powershell remote. I ran this enable-PSRemoting and now the commands work.